# Let $X=\left \{ f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \;\;\text{sucht that } f(f(x))=x \;\;\;\forall x \in \mathbb{N} \right \}$

Tags: permutations, cardinals

Let $X=\left \{ f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \;\;\text{sucht that } f(f(x))=x \;\;\;\forall x \in \mathbb{N} \right \}$ Then

> $1).$ $X$ is finite
>
> $2).$ $X$ is similar ro $\mathbb{N}$
>
> $3).$$X$ is similar to $\mathbb{R}$
>
> $4).$ $X$ is similar to $P(\mathbb{R})$      (power set of R)

I tried to solve this question but question giving no clue ,i only know one function that is $f(x)=x$ which can satisfies this but only considering this one i can't say option on is right.Also it looks like permutations group $S_{\infty}$ and elements i want to find is of order $2$ . Further i am not getting how to solve ,please give me a hint

Thankyou.

Comment: you can prove $f$ is exactly a order 2 (or 1) element of $S_\infty$

Comment: Given two distinct natural numbers $n$ and $m$, the function $f_{n,m}$ setting $n$ to $m$, $m$ to $n$ and that is the identity outside is a non-trivial element of $X$. Thus, you know at least a countable infinity of them.

Answer (score 3):

Finding an injective function $\Phi:\mathcal P(\Bbb N)\hookrightarrow X$ (and therefore extablishing that $\lvert X\rvert=\lvert\mathcal P(\Bbb N)\rvert=\lvert\Bbb R\rvert$) is quite easy.

Call $\Phi(A):\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ the function such that $\Phi(A)(2n)=2n+1$ and $\Phi(2n+1)=2n$ for all $n\in A$, and such that $\Phi(A)(2k)=2k$ and $\Phi(A)(2k+1)=2k+1$ for all $k\notin A$. You can check that:

- $\Phi(A)\circ \Phi(A)=id_{\Bbb N}$ for all $A$;
- the map $G:X\to \mathcal P(\Bbb N)$, $G(f)=\left\{\frac x2\,:\, x\text{ is even }\land f(x)\ne x\right\}$ satisfies $G\circ \Phi=id_{\mathcal P(\Bbb N)}$.

The discussion is, of course, with the convention $0\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: actually, with this you just say $|X| \ge |\mathbb R|$

Comment: @Exodd Yes, there are a couple of details to fill in. I can't quite explain everything.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to rule out (1) and (4) immediately.  Now, to narrow it down further... consider a related problem of asking how many subsets of $\Bbb N$ have their complement either be infinite or have their complement be an even finite number.

> Why is this related?  Well, consider the special subset of your functions made in the following way: First, choose the fixed points.  Then, for all non-fixed points, pair off consecutively appearing numbers and have these map to eachother.  For instance, if our fixed points were $\{1,3,5,7,9,\dots\}$ then we could have $f(1)=1, f(2)=4, f(3)=3, f(4)=2, f(5)=5, f(6)=8, f(7)=7, f(8)=6,\dots$

You should be able to reason that there are at least $\mathfrak{c}$ many such subsets.

> Overall number of subsets is $\mathfrak{c}$, and we are excluding only a subset of the co-finite subsets of which there are countably many.

It follows there are at least $\mathfrak{c}$ many such functions.